# What sort of OAuth flow should I use for Google Drive integration in my application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm frustrated with Google's OAuth APIs. My use-case just doesn't seem to be covered by the available endpoints. I'm hoping someone with knowledge of the Google Drive OAuth APIs can advise me.

I'm developing a **browser add-on**. This means my app is:

1. Serverless. I don't want to have to maintain a domain and webserver for this project.
2. Open-source, so it's trivial to extract any secrets packaged with the code for anyone who can install the add-on. Therefore any information distributed with the add-on has to be considered public.

I want to add Google Drive integration so the user can store app configuration data on Drive so as to sync between devices (the WebExtensions `browser.storage.sync` API is not sufficient, because there's too much data). My requirements are:

1. The user should not have to log-in to Google Drive more than, say, once a month. Certainly not hourly, or each time they use the add-on.
2. This should work across multiple devices for the same Google Drive account.
3. If Alice authorizes MyApp to access alice@google.com, and Eve extracts the OAuth client ID/secret or other info from the MyApp source code, it should be impossible for Eve to access alice@google.com without knowing Alice's Google password.

None of the flows documented on the Google website seem to fulfill these two requirements. I tried the [server-side](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer), since I thought the refresh tokens would fulfill requirement (1), but it seems Google only issue a refresh token the *first* time I request one. After that I just get a short-lived (one hour) access token. So this violates requirement (2) because whichever device talks to Google first will be the only one with a refresh token.

Comment: Doesn't Google allow [Cross-client](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth#policy) identity? So the user only has to give authorization once to the same logical application.

Comment: @Jescanellas I don't think that really covers the case of a user running the same app on multiple devices. That sounds more like it's for apps with multiple distributed components, like a server and a mobile app.

Comment: I see, unfortunately, I don't think what you are trying to do is possible